# Local host port forwarding using AWS

Tags: port-forwarding, amazon-web-services, localhost

I'm a little new to the networking side. I want to have my website running on my comouter to be avialable via the internet,I know of services such as localtunnel,serveo,ngrok but I dont want to use them. Is there any way I can expose it to the internet? I have an AWS VPS. I don't have any router or any other stuff. Can you please guide me through the steps or is there some reference material?

Comment: Do you want to move the whole website to AWS, or do you want to keep it hosted on your own computer and only provide access through AWS?

Comment: Keep it hosted on my localhost

Comment: Little confused here. What do you mean by localhost when you have an AWS EC2 instance (VPS)?